# Meaning of 五 in A: 放肆！B: 你爹放五!

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase, slang

I'm reading a short story and I wondered what 五 means here but I guess it's 'slang'.

A: 放肆！

B retorted back: 你爹放五!

(Sorry for not putting any research result, can't find any, I only know that 五 is sometimes used to replaced 我 or 无).

Comment: 肆 can mean four. So 放五 is made up after 放肆. It is not a fixed expression.

Comment: It is like changing the English expression "raining cats and dogs" to " raining cows and horses"

Comment: 放肆 e.g. bkrs:wanton
unbridled
presumptuous
impudent 放肆诬蔑 wantonly vilify
放肆的行为 unbridled behaviour
极为放肆 throw all restraint to the winds
胆敢如此放肆! How dare you take such liberties!
他这样做太放肆了。 It is too presumptuous of him to do so.不要太放肆了。 Don't be too unrestricted.
肆 an elaborate form of "four"

Comment: +1, it's funny one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a funny one!

As 5 (五) is bigger than 4 (肆)， it could imply B is one higher generation than A. That's why B said 你爹（your father, 放五）， implying "I am your father"(as you are "放肆" and I am "放五"！). This is like saying "我是你爹，放五！"

I really love this joke! Couldn't help laughing...

PS： better put a comma in the middle "你爹，放五！"

Comment: "你爹" doesn't necessarily imply "I am your father", but +1 for the rest of the answer :) made me laugh as well